How to estimate the required scope BW given rise/fall times?
To be able to capture voltage pulse shapes as short as 0.5ns and with rise and fall times down to 100ps, is there a basic way to roughly estimate the minimum required analog BW and sample rate ect of a scope?

How accurately do you need to capture/display the signal?  Using the 100 ps rise/fall time value, you would need a bandwidth of at least 3.5 GHz, or more depending on the accuracy needed.

Thanks for comment. How do you define accuracy? You don't mean resolution correct? (8-bit 12-bit)

@ty_1917 This PDF from Tek: "Understanding Oscilloscope Bandwidth, Rise Time and Signal Fidelity" may help.

@ty_1917 - I was taking the digital/sampling aspects out the problem for now.  So just to represent in some fashion a 100 ps rise/fall time value, you would need a bandwidth of 3.5 GHz as I said earlier).  If you want to discern artifacts such as ringing or non-monotonic behavior, you might need a bandwidth of 3X-5X higher.
